# Validating a field based on a different database table / entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I am writing an MVC 4 application, and using Entity Framework 4.1. I have a validation question which I cannot seem to find the answer to.

Essentially, I have an Entity (object) called "Product" which contains a field "Name", which must follow strict naming conventions which are defined in a separate Entity called "NamingConvention". When the user enters a value, the system needs to check it against the rules established in the NamingConvention entity, and return an error if need be.

Where should this validation be done, and how? I need to check the NamingConvention entity when doing the validation, which means I would need a database context since I'm referencing a different entity. Is there any validation method which won't require me to create a new context? I was thinking of doing the validation in the Controller, since it already creates a data context, but this doesn't seem like the right place to do it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there going to be only one NamingConvention entity?

Comment: @IronMan84, NamingConvention is the name of the entity (in reality, database table). There are many rows inside.

Comment: Is there one NamingConvention entity for every single other entity?

Comment: @IronMan84, I'm not quite sure what you mean. NamingConvention is a table of "rules" for how a product needs to be named. When a user enters a Name for a Product, the system should validate that value (the Name property) against the NamingConvention rules. Hence, the validation routine needs to perform some database operations to pull the rules and do the checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done things like this using a JQuery post (ajax) call from the webpage where the name is being entered. You then post (the value of name) to a method on your controller which can return a JSON value that contains a flag saying if the validation passed and also a message that you want to return to your user. For example :

Javascript in webpage :

```
$("#name").change(function () {

var nameVal = $(this).val();

$.post(getRoot() + "/NameController/ValidateName", { name: nameVal },
function (data) {
    if (data.valid == "true") {
        alert("A valid name was chosen");
    } else
    {
        alert(data.message);
    }
}, "json");

});
```

Controller (NameController) Code :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ValidateName(string name)
 {
   // actual validation carried out in a static utility class (Utils.IsNameValid)
   // if you are loading the same validation rules from your table each time
   // consider caching the data in the application cache or a static List.

   bool nameIsValid = Utils.IsNameValid(name, out string ErrorMessage);

   JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

   result.Data = new { valid = (nameIsValid "true" : "false"), message = ErrorMessage };

   return result;


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using EF 5 but believe you can use this method ... apologies in advance if I'm misleading you with this answer.

You could do the validation within your context (or a context decorator)

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var products = this.GetChangedProducts();

    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        this.ValidateName(product);
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}

private IEnumerable<Product> GetChangedProducts()
{
    return (
        from entry in _context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        where entry.State != EntityState.Unchanged
        select entry.Entity)
        .OfType<Product>();
}

private void ValidateName(Product product)
{
    //validate here
}
```